# Does Microsoft Azure Translator Speech API provide conversion of Text-To-Speech facility ?

Tags: c#, azure, translation

About Microsoft azure [Translator Speech API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator-speech/) you can convert text-to-speech, but there is no clear code , guidance to do it.

If you have any clue about, please write an example of **TEXT-TO-SPEECH** using azure speech translation API.

Answer (score 0):

After contact to Microsoft support team, TEXT-TO-SPEECH is an separate service, you should have subscription for it, its not include in SPEECH api.